# What is the best way to upload a file with React or JS and Websockets?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file, post, websocket

I am new to React.
And I've done a file upload functionality.
It works well for a small file size, but some files are working not good with it.
So I want to have some advice about the right way. The project works via websockets and with another back-end software (php based), so we need to be in this architecture/style.

How I do it:

1. After a file selection I do this:

> ```
> let reader = new FileReader();
> reader.onloadend = () => {
>               this.setState({
>                 avatarPreview: reader.result,
>                 enableSave: true,
>               });
> }
> ```

2. As a next step I send this base64 raw data (reader.result) via websockets.
3. On the back-end I split this data, do some validation, save the raw data (after base64_decode) to the file and write it to the database.

And all works perfectly, so no issues mostly, but some files - don't work well.
And I want to understand why. As I've analyzed - the websocket's frame can be huge and file can't be split because of it. So the problem is not in the file size. Also, not all the files have a big size too. Probably, the issue is in the main logic.

Is it ok to send a base64 raw data to the backend and after write it manually to a file and to the database?
Or do I need to create another one new endpoint, kind of a RestFull API access for a POST queries? In the [official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#the-file-input-tag) nothing about upload, only about file selection. Google has different results, so what is the best way?

Comment: Why would you use web sockets for this, rather than just a normal HTTP PUT?  Why would you use base64 for this, thereby adding 33% overhead in size and extra CPU, when you could just send binary data?

Comment: >Why would you use web sockets for this
because the project has this architecture and was done before me (3 different frontend apps and one backend for them all, all the data are going via websokects)

Comment: So, rather than adding like 2 lines of code, you'd prefer to write much more, just to handle file uploading in a non-standard way, with no optimization by the browser and zero benefit to your use case?  That sounds like a bad idea.  And even if you do send via Web Socket, why not binary?

Comment: `Why would you use base64` React displays it after a file selection in this format. If you can give more better way, I will be happy to know about.

Comment: I doubt React is creating this restriction.  Based on your code, it looks to me like you're reading the file as base64 (`readAsDataURL()`), but that part of the code is missing so it's hard to say for sure.  Rather than doing all of that, just take the reference to the file and use it as a normal request body.  `fetch('/upload', { method: 'PUT', body: file})`  And then, you're done for the client-side.  Server-side is a breeze.... `$_FILES`.